# Reciprocity for branching rules of $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb C)$

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, branching-rules

[Separated from [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/701677/correspondence-of-representation-theory-between-mathrmgl-n-mathbb-c-and)]

If I have information about the restriction of representations of the general linear group, can I make any statements about the induction (by Frobenius reciprocity)? E.g. I know $$\mathrm{res}^{\mathrm{GL}_n}_{\mathrm{GL}_k\times \mathrm{GL}_{n-k}} V(\lambda)_n \cong \bigoplus_{\alpha, \beta} c_{\alpha, \beta}^\lambda V(\alpha)_k \otimes V(\beta)_{n-k}$$
where $V(\lambda)_n$ is the irreducible polynomial representations corresponding to a partition (or Young diagram) $\lambda$ of $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb C)$ and $c^\lambda_{\alpha,\beta}$ are the Littlewood-Richardson numbers. Is it true that
$$ \mathrm{ind}_{\mathrm{GL}_k\times \mathrm{GL}_{n-k}}^{\mathrm{GL}_n} V(\alpha)_k \otimes V(\beta)_{n-k} \cong \bigoplus_\lambda c_{\alpha,\beta}^\lambda V(\lambda)_n ?$$
(I know it is not but true but it should be true up to being semi-simple.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is **not** true that
$$\mathrm{ind}_{\mathrm{GL}_k\times \mathrm{GL}_{n-k}}^{\mathrm{GL}_n} V(\alpha)_k \otimes V(\beta)_{n-k} \cong \bigoplus_\lambda c_{\alpha,\beta}^\lambda V(\lambda)_n.$$
Frobenius reciprocity states that
$$\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathrm{GL}_n}( \mathrm{ind}_{\mathrm{GL}_k\times \mathrm{GL}_{n-k}}^{\mathrm{GL}_n} V(\alpha)_k \otimes V(\beta)_{n-k} ,V(\lambda)_n) \cong \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathrm{GL}_k \times \mathrm{GL}_{n-k}}(V(\alpha)_k \otimes V(\beta)_{n-k},\mathrm{res}^{\mathrm{GL}_n}_{\mathrm{GL}_k\times \mathrm{GL}_{n-k}} V(\lambda)_n) \cong \mathbb C^{c^\lambda_{\alpha,\beta}}$$
and thus there is a surjection 
$$\mathrm{ind}_{\mathrm{GL}_k\times \mathrm{GL}_{n-k}}^{\mathrm{GL}_n} V(\alpha)_k \otimes V(\beta)_{n-k} \twoheadrightarrow \bigoplus_\lambda c_{\alpha,\beta}^\lambda V(\lambda)_n.$$
More can hardly be said. In particular $\bigoplus_\lambda c_{\alpha,\beta}^\lambda V(\lambda)_n$ is finite dimensional but 
$$\mathrm{ind}_{\mathrm{GL}_k\times \mathrm{GL}_{n-k}}^{\mathrm{GL}_n} V(\alpha)_k \otimes V(\beta)_{n-k} \cong \bigoplus_{\mathrm{GL_n}/(\mathrm{GL}_k\times \mathrm{GL}_{n-k})} V(\alpha)_k \otimes V(\beta)_{n-k} $$
is infinite dimensional.

Comment: Do you happen to know how this changes if we use coinduction instead, considering these as algebraic groups? I think that should keep it finite dimensional.

Comment: To show the last isomorphism, note that ${ind}_{{GL}_k\times {GL}_{n-k}}^{{GL}_n} - = \mathbb Z{GL}_n \otimes_{\mathbb Z({GL}_k\times {GL}_{n-k})} - $ and $Z{GL}_n \cong \bigoplus_{{GL_n}/({GL}_k\times {GL}_{n-k})} \mathbb Z({GL}_k\times {GL}_{n-k})$ as ${GL}_k\times {GL}_{n-k}$-representation. Coinduction can be expressed as ${Hom}_{{GL}_k\times {GL}_{n-k}}(\mathbb Z{GL}_n, - ) \cong \prod_{{GL_n}/({GL}_k\times {GL}_{n-k})} -$. So the coinduction is even bigger. Frobenius reciprocity would give an injection to the coinduction instead of the surjection from the induction.

Comment: Maybe you are thinking of these modules as comodules over the coalgebra $\mathbb Z[GL_n]$ as described in Green's book "Polynomial Representations of GL_n". There the coinduction actually gives equality. This is the same as modules over the Schur algebra.

Comment: Sorry, I might have been a bit unclear. I meant the induction we usually consider within the category of algebraic representations. The reason I called this coinduction is that it provides the "wrong" adjoint of restriction compared to what we usually think of as induction without restrictions on the category (for some reason, I cannot get it right in my head right now whether that makes it a left- or a right adjoint).

Comment: You mean the same as what I described in my second comment. If you want everything to become a lot clearer, I recommend looking at Green's book!